# Set unique name to image when downloaded

Tags: javascript, php, md5

I would like to know how I can make this work. I have an md5 code generator so it could give unique names to each image that is downloaded but it cant seem to work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


var element = $("#firstshirt"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable

    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^torcdesign.com:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "$confirm_coded").attr("href", newData);
    });

});

</script>

 <?PHP
$confirm_coded=md5(uniqid(rand())); ?>
```

Comment: I don't understand.. you want the image that you download from the server to have a MD5 name?

Comment: In your JavaScript, replace `$confirm_coded` with `<?php echo $confirm_coded ?>`

Comment: @CapitalC  works great thank you. by any chance do you happen to know how i can upload the image to database folder on submit. this is the code for transforming div to image i would like to upload it on submit and not have to deal with downloading it and then uploading separately